# Form label takes more space than it needs

Tags: html, css, html-table

The layout of my form is three columns: the first the label, the second for the input, and the third for the units (cm, kg etc.). Everything has been given inside a table in the form. But the first column takes more more (horizontal) space than it should. It has no padding, margin nor border. Here's my code:

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #222222;
}

table {
 width: 100%;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

input {
 background-color: #DACBDF;
 padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
 width: 91.5%;
 font-family: Georgia;
 font-size: 13px;
 border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}

input:hover {
 border: 1px solid green;
}

input:focus {
 background-color: #DACBFF;
 border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}

input[type="submit"] {
 font: 13px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
 width: auto;
 border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
 color: #222222;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
 background: #4691A4;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

#wgCalc, #hsCalc, #bfCalc, #ccCalc, #apCalc {
 height: 33px;
 width: 16.5%;
 z-index: 2;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 8px;
}

#container {
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border: 3px solid #888888;
 width: 30%;
 z-index: 1;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

#container h3 {
 text-align: center;
}

.menu {
 width: 30%;
 height: 35px;
 margin: 60px auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.tabOn {
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #EEEEEE !important;
 border: 2px solid blue;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
}

.tabOff {
 background-color: #BBBBBB;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #888888 !important;
 border: 2px solid navy;
 text-align: center;
}

.tabOff a {
 color: #4422FF;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.tabOff a:hover {
 color: #4691A4;
}

.image-holder {
 width: 40%;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

.warning {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #FF0000;
}

.result {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Body Fat Calculator</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fcalc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="menu">
  <div id="wgCalc" class="tabOff"><a href="weightGoal.html">Weight Goal</a></div>
  <div id="hsCalc" class="tabOff"><a href="howSexy.html">How Sexy</a></div>
  <div id="bfCalc" class="tabOn">Body Fat</div>
  <div id="ccCalc" class="tabOff"><a href="circExp.html">Circ. Expect.</a></div>
  <div id="apCalc" class="tabOff"><a href="absPower.html">Absolute Power</a></div>
 </div>
 <div id="container">
 <div class="image-holder">
  <img src="EnData.png" width="100%" />
 </div>
 <h3>BODY FAT CALCULATOR</h3>
 <form id="bodyFatCalc" name="bodyFatCalc" method="post" autocomplete="off" onSubmit="formData(); return false;">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><label>Height:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="height" name="height" value="" maxlength="5" /></td>
    <td>cm</td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td><label>Navel:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="navel" name="navel" value="" maxlength="5" /></td>
    <td>cm</td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td><label>Neck:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="neck" name="neck" value="" maxlength="4" /></td>
    <td>cm</td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td><label>Weight:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" value="" maxlength="4" /></td>
    <td>kg</td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" id="calculate" name="calculate" value="Calculate" /></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
 <p id="warning" class="warning"></p>
 <p id="result_p" class="result"></p>
 <p id ="result_w" class="result"></p>
</div></body>
</html>
```

Can you please help me find out why?

BTW, I tried giving `td {width: auto}` but it only worsened the case.

UPDATE: It seems my question is not clear and concise enough. What I want is that `td` tags to take the width of whatever is inside them...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want the label to be closer to the right? Do you want the input box to stretch out further?

Comment: @ChristopherMesser I want the td that holds the label to take only as much space as it needs, i.e, its width should be only as wide as the longest label. You can think of it as width: auto

Comment: what you are asking for is not possible.  If your table is set to have a `width:100%` then the `td`s will widen-up to take up the space available so that the table is using its given width.  What you might have to do is define which columns need to have a variable width and which ones will be static. (you cannot have it both ways)

Comment: @ochi thanx a lot. Please, post it as an answer so that I can choose it as the best answer.

Comment: You should not be using tables for layout in the first place. This layout can be achieved very simply in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible.

If your table is set to have a `width:100%` then the `td`s will widen-up to take up the space available so that the table is using its prescribed width.

What you might have to do is define which columns need to have a variable width and which ones will be static. (you cannot have it both ways)

Something along the lines of:

```
tr > td:last-of-type, tr > td:first-of-type {
  width: 50px !important; /* adjust width as necessary to fit longest word */
}

/* changed this to 'input' */
input{
    width: 95%;
    /* other properties */
}
```

I reduced your given code to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

**See running demo:**

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

input {
  background-color: #DACBDF;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
  width: 95%;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}

input:hover {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

input:focus {
  background-color: #DACBFF;
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  font: 13px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
  color: #222222;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #4691A4;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}


tr > td:last-of-type, tr > td:first-of-type {
  width: 50px !important; /* adjust width as necessary to fit longest word */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Height:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="height" name="height" value="" maxlength="5" /></td>
    <td>cm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Navel:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="navel" name="navel" value="" maxlength="5" /></td>
    <td>cm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Neck:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="neck" name="neck" value="" maxlength="4" /></td>
    <td>cm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Weight:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" value="" maxlength="4" /></td>
    <td>kg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" id="calculate" name="calculate" value="Calculate" /></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `border-collapse: collapse;` to  `table`, that helps a little bit...:

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #222222;
}

table {
 width: 100%;
 white-space: nowrap;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

input {
 background-color: #DACBDF;
 padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
 width: 91.5%;
 font-family: Georgia;
 font-size: 13px;
 border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}

input:hover {
 border: 1px solid green;
}

input:focus {
 background-color: #DACBFF;
 border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}

input[type="submit"] {
 font: 13px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
 width: auto;
 border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
 color: #222222;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
 background: #4691A4;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

#wgCalc, #hsCalc, #bfCalc, #ccCalc, #apCalc {
 height: 33px;
 width: 16.5%;
 z-index: 2;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 8px;
}

#container {
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border: 3px solid #888888;
 width: 30%;
 z-index: 1;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

#container h3 {
 text-align: center;
}

.menu {
 width: 30%;
 height: 35px;
 margin: 60px auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.tabOn {
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #EEEEEE !important;
 border: 2px solid blue;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
}

.tabOff {
 background-color: #BBBBBB;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #888888 !important;
 border: 2px solid navy;
 text-align: center;
}

.tabOff a {
 color: #4422FF;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.tabOff a:hover {
 color: #4691A4;
}

.image-holder {
 width: 40%;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

.warning {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #FF0000;
}

.result {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Body Fat Calculator</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fcalc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="menu">
  <div id="wgCalc" class="tabOff"><a href="weightGoal.html">Weight Goal</a></div>
  <div id="hsCalc" class="tabOff"><a href="howSexy.html">How Sexy</a></div>
  <div id="bfCalc" class="tabOn">Body Fat</div>
  <div id="ccCalc" class="tabOff"><a href="circExp.html">Circ. Expect.</a></div>
  <div id="apCalc" class="tabOff"><a href="absPower.html">Absolute Power</a></div>
 </div>
 <div id="container">
 <div class="image-holder">
  <img src="EnData.png" width="100%" />
 </div>
 <h3>BODY FAT CALCULATOR</h3>
 <form id="bodyFatCalc" name="bodyFatCalc" method="post" autocomplete="off" onSubmit="formData(); return false;">
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><label>Height:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="height" name="height" value="" maxlength="5" /></td>
    <td>cm</td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td><label>Navel:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="navel" name="navel" value="" maxlength="5" /></td>
    <td>cm</td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td><label>Neck:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="neck" name="neck" value="" maxlength="4" /></td>
    <td>cm</td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td><label>Weight:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" value="" maxlength="4" /></td>
    <td>kg</td>
   </tr><tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" id="calculate" name="calculate" value="Calculate" /></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
 <p id="warning" class="warning"></p>
 <p id="result_p" class="result"></p>
 <p id ="result_w" class="result"></p>
</div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir, it didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

```
table{table-layout: fixed;}
td:first-of-type{width: your-width;}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot, but it didn't work... Do you mind elaborating a bit, sir?

Comment: @NimaBavari sir))) i like it) What specifically did not work
can you give a picture,  What should happen in the end

Comment: instead of having multiple answers, edit one and remove the other one (unless they are completely different answers that deserve to stand on their own)

Comment: @DimitriyLishtvan (+1) to both your answers for further explanation. What I was asking is, why can't it just take an auto-width?

Comment: @NimaBavari because your table has 100% width, remove it - and you will got auto-width for column

Comment: @DmitriyLishtvan I removed it but still, it's even worse.

Comment: @NimaBavari input{    box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%;}